# How to display HTTP 401 basic authentication dialog

Tags: javascript, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, http-status-code-401, httpserver

I am new to web development. I have Android application that hosts some web pages using HTTPServer. I am using Netty to decode/encode request/responses. Now, I want to display basic authentication dialog when someone navigates to the my webpage. Something like this: [image]

Can I get some pointers ? Is it something HTTP built in functionality, any RFC ? Do I need to write some java script ? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to send the appropriate headers when a client requests a resource you want to require authentication for.

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Area"
```

The client can then retry the request while sending a base64 encoded header in the format `username:password`.

```
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
```

See also:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: Thanks Brad. Will this display dialog automatically ?

Comment: @ArjunPatel, It is up to the client to choose how to handle the authentication.  Most clients will display a dialog.

Comment: @Brad Chrome doesn't anymore?

Comment: @ArturasM Chrome still does basic auth.

Comment: @Brad probably won't after you update. Mine used to do back in the day... Updates nowadays...

Comment: @ArturasM You're wrong about that.  Chrome works fine with basic auth.  Basic auth isn't going away.