# HTTP auth in django

Tags: python, django, http

Is there a way to raise the following in django?

[image]

Basically, I would like to have a view that is like:

```
def my_view(request):
    if request.user.is_superuser:
        pass
    else:
        raise Http Auth
```

Comment: @JuniorCompressor I don't think so. I already have the user object, I'm not concerned about logging them in. These are specific credentials for a page.

Comment: We normally do this at the `nginx` level, not Django

Comment: See also this answer for a hint: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177325/how-to-display-http-401-basic-authentication-dialog

Comment: Yes - it's called HTTP Basic Auth, and you can see how to implement it in Django in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/auth-remote-user/)