# How do I use the Login Event in Electron Framework?

Tags: javascript, node.js, chromium, electron

I would like some help understanding how the `Event: 'login'` feature in Electron Framework works. Is it the low level implementation of the Password Autofill/Remember Password feature common in browsers? I would like to use this to autofill a password in a webpage's login flow e.g.

```
const electron = require('electron')
const {app,BrowserWindow} = electron

app.on('ready', ()=>{
    let win = new BrowserWindow({
        width:800,
        height:600
    })
//This is where I'm confused
app.on('login', (event, webContents, request, authInfo, callback) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  callback('my_username', 'my_password');
});
//How to implement autofill to https://accounts.google.com?



    win.loadURL('https://accounts.google.com')

});
```

[Here is the link to the specification in their docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/app/#event-login)

Answer (score 2):

It's not used for autofilling, it's used for basic auth. When you get those annoying browser prompts for user and password.

[How to display HTTP 401 basic authentication dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177325/how-to-display-http-401-basic-authentication-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

It can also be used to support Proxies on a Corporate network. e.g. Basic, NTLM, etc. This'd be in response to a 407.

**Update August 2023**

Adding a basic example. The core code here needs to be application specific.

```
// Runs when electron requires credentials in response to a 401 or 407
app.on('login', async (event, webContents, request, authInfo, callback) => {
  // Call prevent default immediately as a delay, such as prompting on the UI for credentials, will
  // cause the default action to occur.
  event.preventDefault()

  // If the proxy credentials are cached use them otherwise prompt on the UI
  const [username, password] = <custom code to retrieve credentials, I display a prompt for the user to enter the credentials>

  callback(username, password)
})
```

Comment: A code example and link to documentation would improve the quality of this answer.

Comment: Added an example, but the core code is fundamentally specific to your scenario