# How to use Electron's Login event? Can you give an example?

Tags: electron

How to use electron's login event? When to use this event? Can you give an example?
doc: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#event-login

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use the Login Event in Electron Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281113/how-do-i-use-the-login-event-in-electron-framework)

Comment: Duplicate: [How do I use the Login Event in Electron Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38281113/how-do-i-use-the-login-event-in-electron-framework)